# combining multiple sheets on excel

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to combine all the excel sheets from one folder and I always got the below error. 'TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not list. please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = ['pythonProject']
combine = pd.DataFrame()

#2nd
for j in os.listdir(path):
df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=3)
combine = combine.append(df, ignore_index=True)

print(combine)
```

Comment: @ xcodz-dot here is my actual path and i still face the same error. path = r'C:\Users\ACER\PycharmProjects\pythonProject'

Answer (score 0):

you accidently made path a list because of `[` and `]`. try the following code

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
path = 'pythonProject'
combine = pd.DataFrame()

#2nd
for j in os.listdir(path):
    df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=3)
combine = combine.append(df, ignore_index=True)

print(combine)
```